# Import bootstrap js more than once doesn't work typescript

Tags: jquery, typescript, symfony, webpack

I'm working in a web app that uses Symfony 4.1 and Typescript 3.0.3 with symfony Webpack encore plugin.

The problem is that when I import bootstrap in my **./assets/js/app.ts**:

```
import 'bootstrap';

jQuery(function () {
    $('#clock-timetable').popover();
    $('#form_popover').popover();
});
```

And import again in another file **./assets/js/home/example.ts**:

```
import 'bootstrap';
import 'bootstrap-select';

export class Example {
    readonly element: JQuery;

    constructor(element: JQuery) {
        this.element = element;
    }

    render(data: Array<SelectorData>): void {
        for (let obj of data) {
            this.element.append("<option data-icon='fa fa-map-marker' value='" + obj.code + "'>" + obj.name + "</option>");
        }

        this.element.selectpicker('refresh');
    }
}
```

The selector doesn't work. But if I change in my **app.ts** script the import of bootstrap and imports only **'bootstrap/js/dist/popover'** it works. Note that JS console don't throw any warnings either TS compiler.

My **webpack.config.js**:

```
var Encore = require('@symfony/webpack-encore');

Encore
    .setOutputPath('public/build/')
    .setPublicPath('/build')
    .cleanupOutputBeforeBuild()
    .enableBuildNotifications()
    .autoProvidejQuery()
    .enableSourceMaps(!Encore.isProduction())
    .enableVersioning(Encore.isProduction())
    .addEntry('js/app', './assets/js/app.ts')
    .addEntry('js/home/example', './assets/js/home/example.ts')
    .enableTypeScriptLoader()
;

module.exports = Encore.getWebpackConfig();
```

My **tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
  "include": [
    "./assets/js/**/*"
  ]
}
```

My **package.json**:

```
{
    "devDependencies": {
        "@symfony/webpack-encore": "^0.20.0",
        "webpack-notifier": "^1.6.0"
    },
    "license": "UNLICENSED",
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev-server": "encore dev-server",
        "dev": "encore dev",
        "watch": "encore dev --watch",
        "build": "encore production"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/bootstrap": "^4.1.2",
        "@types/bootstrap-select": "^1.11.1",
        "@types/jquery": "^3.3.6",
        "@types/jqueryui": "^1.12.4",
        "bootstrap": "^4.1.3",
        "bootstrap-select": "^1.13.2",
        "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
        "jquery": "^3.3.1",
        "jquery-ui": "^1.12.1",
        "popper.js": "^1.14.4",
        "ts-loader": "^3.5.0",
        "typeface-montserrat": "^0.0.54",
        "typescript": "^3.0.3"
    }
}
```

**base.html.twig:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{{ asset('images/favicon.ico') }}"/>

            <title>{% block title %} {{ 'company.name' | trans }} {% endblock %}</title>

            {% block stylesheets %}
                <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ asset('build/css/app.css') }}">
            {% endblock %}
        </head>
        <body>
        {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\CommonController::navBar')) }}

        {% block body %}{% endblock %}

        {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\CommonController::footer')) }}

        {% block javascripts %}
            <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="{{ asset('build/js/app.js') }}"></script>
        {% endblock %}
        </body>
    </html>
```

My **index.html.twig**:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}

    <div class="container">
        {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\HomeController::example')) }}

    </div>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}
    <script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" src="{{ asset('build/js/home/example.js') }}"></script>
{% endblock %}
```

**QUESTION:** Why I cannot import twice bootstrap in differents files?

**EDIT**: Here an example of the problem: https://github.com/soasada/example-project

Comment: I don't know the answer based on the code, but if you publish a repository, I'll play with it.

Comment: Hello Matt, here you have a full working example of the problem: https://github.com/soasada/example-project, I provide you a vagrantfile to play with the example. If you remove the import 'bootstrap' in the app.ts script the selector code in the home.ts works perfectly. Where am I wrong? I think that I'm forgetting something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so based in the Matt McCutchen answer I have been able to fix the bug, what I needed was a shared entry with the main dependencies of the project. This is possible with the **.createSharedEntry(name: string, files: Array[string])** method of Symfony webpack encore.

Image that you need jquery, jquery-ui, bootstrap and bootstrap-select javascript dependencies, this line makes a shared entry with all packaged dependencies:

```
.createSharedEntry('js/common', ['jquery', 'bootstrap', 'bootstrap-select', 'jquery-ui'])
```

In https://github.com/soasada/example-project have an example of the solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are making and loading two separate Webpack bundles, each of which contains a copy of Bootstrap, and each copy associates a click event handler with elements with the `data-toggle="dropdown"` attribute.  `bootstrap-select` is setting this attribute on the menu it creates.  So when you click on the menu, both event handlers run and try to handle the event.  Obviously that can't be expected to work.

One approach to fix this would be to put all your code in a single Webpack bundle.  I imagine there are other possible approaches, but I'm not familiar with the best practices in this area.